# Is it possible to create single path SVG for below image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[image]

- I was able to create this(however it has the transparent part at the center - want it solid white)
- "M62,31c0,17.1-13.9,31-31,31S0,48.1,0,31S13.9,0,31,0S62,13.9,62,31z M48.5,43.9L46,44l-7.3-11.3 c-0.5-0.8-1.4-1.2-2.3-1.2L26.7,32l-0.2-2.8l9.6-2.7c0.9-0.3,1.4-1.2,1.2-2.1c-0.2-0.9-1.2-1.4-2.1-1.2l-8.9,2.5L25.9,19 c-0.1-1.4-1.3-2.5-2.7-2.4c-1.4,0.1-2.5,1.3-2.4,2.7l0.9,15.6c0.1,1.4,1.3,2.5,2.7,2.4l10.7-0.6L42.5,48c0.5,0.7,1.3,1.2,2.1,1.2 c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0l4-0.1c1.4-0.1,2.5-1.2,2.5-2.6C51.1,44.9,49.9,43.8,48.5,43.9z M23.4,6c-2.8,0-5.1,2.3-5.1,5.1s2.3,5.1,5.1,5.1    s5.1-2.3,5.1-5.1S26.2,6,23.4,6z M35.2,42.4c-0.2,5.7-4.8,10.2-10.5,10.2c-5.8,0-10.5-4.7-10.5-10.5c0-3.5,1.8-6.7,4.5-8.6v-3.9 c-4.6,2.3-7.9,7-7.9,12.5c0,7.7,6.2,13.9,13.9,13.9c6.1,0,11.3-4,13.2-9.5L35.2,42.4z"
- Path 1 result : [image]
- Later, I was able to extract another path for the center figure, which is:
- "M40.3,40.3c0.1,1.4-1,2.6-2.5,2.6l-4,0.1c0,0-0.1,0-0.1,0c-0.9,0-1.7-0.4-2.1-1.2l-7.3-11.3l-10.7,0.6 c-1.4,0.1-2.6-1-2.7-2.4L10,13.3c-0.1-1.4,1-2.6,2.4-2.7c1.4-0.1,2.6,1,2.7,2.4l0.4,6.8l8.9-2.5c0.9-0.2,1.8,0.3,2.1,1.2 c0.3,0.9-0.3,1.8-1.2,2.1l-9.6,2.7l0.2,2.8l9.6-0.5c0.9,0,1.8,0.4,2.3,1.2L35.1,38l2.5-0.1C39.1,37.8,40.3,38.9,40.3,40.3z M12.5,10.2c2.8,0,5.1-2.3,5.1-5.1S15.4,0,12.5,0C9.7,0,7.4,2.3,7.4,5.1S9.7,10.2,12.5,10.2z M13.9,46.6c-5.8,0-10.5-4.7-10.5-10.5 c0-3.5,1.8-6.7,4.5-8.6v-3.9C3.2,25.9,0,30.6,0,36.1C0,43.8,6.2,50,13.9,50c6.1,0,11.3-4,13.2-9.5l-2.7-4.1 C24.2,42,19.6,46.6,13.9,46.6z"
- Path 2 result : [image]

Looking for a single path SVG, which creates an exact image like [image].

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No. A single path can only have one fill colour so you can't have a partial white, partial blue single path.

Comment: Thank you @Robert for your inputs.
Is it possible to merge two paths in one - just curious!

Comment: Generally you can just concatenate the d attribute values.

Comment: Thanks a ton, will try to do that.

Comment: For editting d-paths see: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Haters will say I'm cheating. And they will be absolutely right.

```html
<svg
  width="60"
  height="60"
  style="background-color: LightSalmon; border-radius: 100%"
  viewBox="1 1 60 60"
>
<path d="M62 31c0 17.1-13.9 31-31 31S0 48.1 0 31 13.9 0 31 0s31 13.9 31 31zM48.5 43.9L46 44l-7.3-11.3c-.5-.8-1.4-1.2-2.3-1.2l-9.7.5-.2-2.8 9.6-2.7c.9-.3 1.4-1.2 1.2-2.1-.2-.9-1.2-1.4-2.1-1.2l-8.9 2.5-.4-6.7c-.1-1.4-1.3-2.5-2.7-2.4-1.4.1-2.5 1.3-2.4 2.7l.9 15.6c.1 1.4 1.3 2.5 2.7 2.4l10.7-.6L42.5 48c.5.7 1.3 1.2 2.1 1.2h.1l4-.1c1.4-.1 2.5-1.2 2.5-2.6-.1-1.6-1.3-2.7-2.7-2.6zM23.4 6c-2.8 0-5.1 2.3-5.1 5.1s2.3 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1-2.3 5.1-5.1S26.2 6 23.4 6zm11.8 36.4c-.2 5.7-4.8 10.2-10.5 10.2-5.8 0-10.5-4.7-10.5-10.5 0-3.5 1.8-6.7 4.5-8.6v-3.9c-4.6 2.3-7.9 7-7.9 12.5C10.8 49.8 17 56 24.7 56c6.1 0 11.3-4 13.2-9.5l-2.7-4.1z"/>
</svg>
```

The real answer is that compound paths in a single `<path/>` element can only have one style (as the style is defined by the said path).